# how to get rid of computer mites?

Tags: cleaning

My laptop is infested with these white stuff which I dismissed as dust initially until I saw it move. There are at least 15 of theses crawling about my keyboard now, and I saw some slip beneath the keys. Any idea how to remove permanently?
https://youtube.com/shorts/WkNtnC_dIpQ?si=Sho0qXvP48MsySmT

Comment: I think this is a first for SuperUser

Comment: Actually no. We had questions on removing ants in the old days

Comment: And the user has already asked the same question https://superuser.com/questions/1821553/how-to-kill-all-white-mites-from-laptop

Comment: The video show utterly nothing. It just shows a slow video of the keyboard with no sign of mites.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a repost of a now [closed off topic question](https://superuser.com/q/1821553/167207).

Comment: If they are mites, then they will not just be on your laptop. It is more than likely that your home is infested. Cleaning the laptop would therefore not help.

Comment: First give 'em two verbal and one written warnings.

Comment: What kind of computer has bugs even when powered off?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 There is one crawling (white spot) just below the keyboard and left of the track pad.

Comment: @DavidPostill Okay. I see it now. Freezing the computer overnight or bug spray will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working out what the source of the insects is probably a good start. These might be various food related pests, or termites for example. *Indirect* application on insecticide, or fumigating your living space might not be a bad idea.

I would suggest using an air duster to blow out your keyboard after that.

There's also products for deep cleaning keyboards and other electronics - Cyber Clean's the brand I use, though I believe color coral is pretty much identical. Both have a yellow versions for PC use  (the blue version for cars is a little stiffer IME). There's also knockoff versions which are a little stickier.  This would cause your bugs to stick to it and not your keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

If those are really mites, they cant survive freezing temperatures.  Put the laptop in a plastic bag and seal it.  Then stick it in a freezer overnight.  That should kill the mites.  Take the bag out of the freezer and let it warm up to room temperature.  Open up the laptop and blow it out with canned air.